# Not understanding what this means in google play store email

Tags: android, react-native

```
Please also note that you will have to set the non-compliant APK referenced above to DEACTIVATED before you make a new submission of the compliant APKs
```

This is the GitHub issue we are trying to address

https://github.com/razorpay/react-native-razorpay/issues/336